# List of critical points

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, maximum

In *TI-Nspire CX CAS*, writing:

```
exp▶list(fMax(sin(x),x,0,10),x)
```

I get:

> {((π)/(2)),((5*π)/(2))}

while in *Wolfram Mathematica*, writing:

```
Maximize[{Sin[x], 0 <= x <= 10}, x]
```

I get:

> {1, {x -> π/2}}

Is there a way to get the result above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Reduce[{Sin'[x] == 0, Sin''[x] <= 0, 0 <= x <= 10}, x, Reals]
```

> x == π/2 || x == (5 π)/2

```
List @@ %
```

> {x == π/2, x == (5 π)/2}

Alternatively,

```
Solve[{Sin'[x] == 0, Sin''[x] <= 0, 0 <= x <= 10}, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> π/2}, {x -> (5 π)/2}}

```
 x /. %
```

> {π/2, (5 π)/2}

or

```
x /. {ToRules[Reduce[{Sin'[x] == 0, Sin''[x] <= 0, 0 <= x <= 10}, x, Reals]]}
```

> {π/2, (5 π)/2}

Answer (score 6):

I would use [`MaxValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxValue) in combination with [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
maxima[{expr_, cond_}, v_] := With[{m = MaxValue[{expr, cond}, v]},
    DeleteDuplicates @ Solve[expr == m && cond, v]
]
```

For your example:

```
maxima[{Sin[x], 0<=x<=10}, x]
```

> {{x -> π/2}, {x -> (5 π)/2}}

Contrast this with the approach in kglr's answer that only looks at critical points:

```
maxima[{Sin[x], -1 <= x <= 1}, x]

Reduce[{Sin'[x]==0,Sin''[x]<=0,-1<=x<=1},x,Reals]
```

> {{x -> 1}}
>
> False